# cabal build-depends: how to find?

Tags: haskell, cabal

How can I find out what needs to go into the module.cabal build-depends? I mean, some modules may already be part of the Haskell platform whilst others may not? How to I find out/know what I must write here so that the module I offer will install with cabal on the majority of Haskell installations "out there"?

My situation is that I have it working on my systems, but cannot remember for what import I actually had to install an other module and what was part of the Haskell Platform that I use. How do I now best find the way from my situation to a cabal installable package?

Comment: `cabal init` with recent version of `cabal`is quite good at inferring the packages; the version constraints are narrow, of course, and based on what you have, e.g. `base ==4.5.*, containers ==0.4.*, mtl ==2.1.*, array ==0.4.*, text ==0.11.*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Cabal to build your project, it will only look at the modules listed in the .cabal file, even if you have other modules installed locally.

So all you have to do is run it as is (with nothing in the depends declaration) and it will give you an error for each module you need to specify. I think the error even tells you the name of the package.

Comment: Can I by the way make arbitrary updates to the description (without updating the rest) after it has been published on hackage?

Comment: @JFritsch - No, updating any part of a package requires uploading an entire new version.